# Consume WCF Service from RPG

Tags: wcf, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Can anyone give me some information on consuming a WCF service from ILERPG?  I have the service written and running, but the only info I can find dates back to 2008.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Klement has a presentation and examples: http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/#HTTPAPI

Comment: Good stuff - what I was looking for... Thanks!